# Extrating email from two tables in sql

Tags: sql, mysql, mariadb

I have two tables User and Email. In Email table, i stored multiple emails of the user. I want to extract only one email for the user. First preference is the email id belongs to @india.org.in. The below query not works for some users.

for example, User 1 has two emails.Email 1: XXXXX@india.org.in, Email2: YYYYYY@gmail.com. By using below query prints YYYYYY@gmail.com. If i use MIN instead of MAX then am getting XXXXX@india.org.in for User 1 and getting wrong for other users.

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    p.first_name,
    p.nationality,
    MAX(IF(e.email LIKE '%india.org.in%', e.email, NULL)) AS email
FROM
    User p
LEFT JOIN
    Email e ON p.name = e.parent
GROUP BY
    p.name, p.first_name, p.nationality;
```

Comment: `Y` comes after `X` alphabetically. Why would you expect any other results?

Comment: May be my query is wrong. I need to print only XXXXX@india.org.in.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: What is MySQL version precisely? *First preference is the email id belongs to @india.org.in.* there exists more than one email in this domain? What value must be returned if there is no emails in this domain but there exists more ерт one email in another domain(s)?

Comment: Is this for one particular user?  Or for every user?  In the latter case, see [groupwise-max]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function as follows:

```
select t.* from
  (SELECT
      p.name,
      p.first_name,
      p.nationality,
      e.email,
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.name order by case when e.email LIKE '%india.org.in%' then 1 else 2 end) AS rn
  FROM User p
  LEFT JOIN Email e ON p.name = e.parent
) t
where rn = 1;
```